# Vulkan - How to enable Synchronization 2 feature?

Tags: vulkan

I am trying to use Vulkan Synchronization2 feature. However, even though I enable it (correctly as far as I can tell), the validation layer reports an error when trying to use vkCmdPipelineBarrier2:

> `Validation Error: [ VUID-vkCmdPipelineBarrier2-synchronization2-03848 ] Object 0: handle = 0x258b5ee3dc0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; | MessageID  = 0xa060404 | vkCmdPipelineBarrier2(): Synchronization2 feature is not enabled The Vulkan spec states: The synchronization2 feature must be enabled (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.211.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdPipelineBarrier2-synchronization2-03848)`

Here is my instance creation code:

```
    DEBUGGER_TRACE("Requested instance layers = {}", desc.required_layers);
    DEBUGGER_TRACE("Requested instance extenstions = {}", desc.required_instance_extentions);

    vk::InstanceCreateInfo createInfo{
        .flags = vk::InstanceCreateFlags(),
        .pApplicationInfo = &appInfo,
        .enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(desc.required_layers.size()),
        .ppEnabledLayerNames = desc.required_layers.data(), // enabled layers
        .enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(desc.required_instance_extentions.size()),
        .ppEnabledExtensionNames = desc.required_instance_extentions.data()
    };

    return std::make_pair(vkr::Instance(context, createInfo), version);
```

And my device creation code:

```
    DEBUGGER_TRACE("Requested device layers = {}", desc.required_layers);
    DEBUGGER_TRACE("Requested device extentions = {}", desc.required_extentions);


    vk::DeviceCreateInfo deviceInfo{
        .pNext = &features,
        .flags = vk::DeviceCreateFlags(),
        .queueCreateInfoCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(deviceCreationDesc.create_info.size()),
        .pQueueCreateInfos = deviceCreationDesc.create_info.data(),
        .enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(desc.required_layers.size()),
        .ppEnabledLayerNames = desc.required_layers.data(),
        .enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(desc.required_extentions.size()),
        .ppEnabledExtensionNames = desc.required_extentions.data(),
        .pEnabledFeatures = &deviceFeatures
    };

    _device = std::make_shared<vkr::Device>(*chosenPhysicalDevice, deviceInfo);
```

My debug traces print the following:

```
Requested instance layers =
{VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation,VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_synchronization2}

Requested instance extensions =
{VK_KHR_surface,VK_KHR_win32_surface,VK_EXT_debug_utils} 

Requested device layers =
{VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation,VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_synchronization2}

Requested device extentions =
{VK_KHR_swapchain,VK_KHR_synchronization2}
```

When using the Vulkan Configurator, I can Force Enable synchronization 2 and everything works just fine.

So what could be wrong? How to enable synchronization 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Synchronization 2 is a set of functionality exposed in two ways. It was originally introduced as a KHR extension to Vulkan 1.0. It was adopted as a core feature for Vulkan 1.3. And while these are largely the same (I have no idea if they're actually identical)... they're still exposed in two *separate* ways, with two different sets of named functions.

You requested the extension, but you tried to *use* the core feature... which you did not request. You need to be consistent: if you want to code against the core feature, you must ask for it as a *feature*, not an extension.

Comment: I still don't understand how to enable it as a core feature. I use Vulkan 1.3.201, and if I don't request the extensions / layers I still get the same error. How do I enable it?

Comment: @EladMaimoni: Your code already passes a list of features to the device upon creation. Add the feature to that list.

Answer (score 2):

I've been digging Internet for this problem. As much as I searched, I couldn't find the answer. But finally I found the solution!

Here are the steps:

1. You should create a VkPhysicalDeviceSynchronization2Features struct.
2. Set it's synchronization2 field to true
3. Finally assgin it to the pNext field of your VkDeviceCreateInfo struct.

Doing the above steps fixed my error.

[This is the source which has more explanation about VkPhysicalDeviceSynchronization2Features struct.](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDeviceSynchronization2Features.html)