# How to enable synchronization 2 when using Vulkan API 1.2?

Tags: vulkan

Up until now, I used the the latest Vulkan API available on my development machine (1.3.201).

`VK_CHECK(vkEnumerateInstanceVersion(&_apiVersion)); // returns 1.3.201`

After some [struggles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73746051/vulkan-how-to-enable-synchronization-2-feature) I managed to use synchronization 2 as a core feature (functions without KHR).

But now, I wish to work with API version 1.2 to be compatible with more devices.
So when initializing `VkApplicationInfo` I set a lower version to the `apiVersion` field:

`appInfo.apiVersion = VK_MAKE_API_VERSION(0, 1, 2, 0);`

In order to use synchronization 2 extension, I pass the following extensions & layers to `vkCreateInstance`:

Extensions:

- VK_KHR_surface
- VK_KHR_win32_surface
- VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2
- VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2
- VK_EXT_debug_utils

Layers:

- VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_synchronization2
- VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation

And these are the extensions and layers I pass to `vkCreateDevice`:

- VK_KHR_create_renderpass2
- VK_KHR_synchronization2
- VK_KHR_swapchain

Layers:

- VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation

This is my device Initialization code:

```
    VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures deviceFeatures{ };
    VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features features12{};
    features12.sType = VkStructureType::VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_VULKAN_1_2_FEATURES;
    features12.timelineSemaphore = true;

    VkDeviceCreateInfo deviceCreateInfo
    {
        .sType = VkStructureType::VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO,
        .pNext = &features12,
        .flags = VkDeviceCreateFlags{},
        .queueCreateInfoCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(createDesc.queu_create_info.size()),
        .pQueueCreateInfos = createDesc.queu_create_info.data(),
        .enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(config.required_layers.size()),
        .ppEnabledLayerNames = config.required_layers.data(),
        .enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(config.required_extentions.size()),
        .ppEnabledExtensionNames = config.required_extentions.data(),
        .pEnabledFeatures = &deviceFeatures
    };
```

Yet, when calling `vkCmdPipelineBarrier2KHR` I get a validation error:

`Validation Error: [ VUID-vkCmdPipelineBarrier2-synchronization2-03848 ] Object 0: handle = 0x20b77c136f0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; | MessageID = 0xa060404 | vkCmdPipelineBarrier2KHR(): Synchronization2 feature is not enabled The Vulkan spec states: The synchronization2 feature must be enabled (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.236.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdPipelineBarrier2-synchronization2-03848)`

Comment: What is `deviceCreateInfoNext`? Did you put all of the things into that linked list you were supposed to?

Comment: You're passing `VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features`  into the `pEnabledFeatures` member of `VkDeviceCreateInfo` but I don't see any indication that's permissible.  Documentation for the former type suggests it can be used only in the pNext chains of either `VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures2` or `VkDeviceCreateInfo`.  As Nicol has said though, you're not showing the initialization of your `pNext` chain.

Comment: My bad, I was trying to copy only the necessary context and did it wrong. I am passing an default VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures into pEnabledFeatures and VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features to pNext. I corrected the question.